# How can I access simultaneously Synology-DSM of multiple NAS on remote Network with only one browser (Firefox)?

Tags: sockets, tcp, connection, port, nas

I have to access simultaneously multiple NAS DSM on a remote Network with Firefox. They are reachable over the Routers-IP and a dedicated port each, like: https:\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000 and https:\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5100 and https:\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5200. The problem is that Firefox loses the connection to the first NAS as soon as I connect to the next NAS. Multiple simultaneous connections are only possible with multiple browsers, why? How can I manage to connect to all NAS simultaneously, only with one browser?

---

I found a workaround.

You can start several separate FireFox profiles in such a way that no instance notices something of the other.

To do this, you have to call FireFox with "-p" and create as many profiles as you need:

Standard-User001

Standard-User002

...

And store them in separate folders:

D:\FirefoxProfile\Standard-User001\

D:\FirefoxProfile\Standard-User002\

...

Then you can create links on your desktop:

"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe" -p "Standard-User001" -no-remote

"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe" -p "Standard-User002" -no-remote

...

Now you have several completely separate FireFox installations.

Answer (score 0):

with Synology NAS, when you login to DSM, the generated `PHPSESSID` cookie is  the same if the domain name is the same, no matter if the specified port in the URL is different. So there is, as far as i know, no way to circumvent this mecanism (needless to say that it is actually a good thing for security in most case).

So the most simple solution i found is to setup CNAMEs on a dynDNS entry, assuming you fullfil the following requirements:

- have your own domain name.
- each DSM is configured to use a different port.
- port forwarding on your router is setup (optional).

Now let's say you have two servers: `nas1` reachable on port 5001, `nas2` on port 5002 and a dynDNS, for instance `nas-is-like.synology.me` ( in DSM, check the "DDNS" tab in "External access" settings from the configuration panel if you need to setup this first ).

Then simply add wanted aliases in your DNS zone:

```
NAME                    TYPE    TARGET
--------------------------------------------------
nas1.youdomain.tk        CNAME  nas-is-like.synology.me.
nas2.youdomain.tk        CNAME  nas-is-like.synology.me.
```

Then you will be able to login on both DSM interfaces ( nas1.youdomain.tk:5001 and nas2.youdomain.tk:5002 ) in the same brower and the same profile.